# AWK returns duplicated record when traversing an array

Tags: awk

I'm agregating data from a 15 M records (file XXX) into arrays with awk. When ENDing the awk, I print every aggregated record (aprox, 2,25 M), but, from time to time, it returns 1 duplicated record. The code (simplified) is like this:

```
awk '{
  id=substr($0,18,25)
  date=substr($0,131,14)
  field_#=substr($0,##,###)               --> Many fields
  key=id "," date
  array_#[key]=array_#[key] + field_#     --> 4 arrays, some using 3 fields
}END{
  for key in array_1{
    print(array_1[key] "," array_2[key] "," array_3[key] "," array_4[key])
  }
}' XXX
```

Is there something in the code that can lead to duplicated records?
Related to this, when this hapens, it raises a "cannot fork" memory error message, as it is using 12 GB out of 16GB that has the machine. Is there any reason that can lead to that fault?

I've already checked that there isn't any special characters in the file, as they could lead to "fake" duplicated keys.

###### DATA

```
INPUT
#...### IDENTIFIER   ####...### VOL_UP    VOL_DOWN  VOL_TOTAL ###...#### YYYYMMDDHHMISS #####
#...### 9876123      ####...### 123456    665204500 665327956 ###...#### 20180529020103 #####
#...### 7854954      ####...### 654       456121    456775    ###...#### 20180529102501 #####
#...### 9876123      ####...### 105251    58044518  58149769  ###...#### 20180529020103 #####

OUTPUT
#...### 9876123      ####...### 228707    723249018 723477725 ###...#### 20180529020103 #####
#...### 7854954      ####...### 654       456121    456775    ###...#### 20180529102501 #####
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post sample(s) of Input and output in your post too for better understanding of question.

Comment: PS. `#` is a comment sign.

Comment: INPUT
#...### IDENTIFIER   ####...### VOL_UP    VOL_DOWN  VOL_TOTAL ###...#### YYYYMMDDHHMISS #####
#...### 9876123      ####...### 123456    665204500 665327956 ###...#### 20180529020103 #####
#...### 7854954      ####...### 654       456121    456775    ###...#### 20180529102501 #####
#...### 9876123      ####...### 105251    58044518  58149769  ###...#### 20180529020103 #####

OUTPUT
#...### 9876123      ####...### 228707    723249018 723477725 ###...#### 20180529020103 #####
#...### 7854954      ####...### 654       456121    456775    ###...#### 20180529102501 #####

Comment: What the script does is adding the VOL fields into the arrays, for every session

Comment: How about you append that data with the original question.